# More HH than HT after tossing $n$ coins

Tags: probability, random-variables

A fair coin is tossed $n\geq 2$ times. Player 1 wins if there are more HH than HT in the sequence, Player 2 wins if there are more HT than HH. Who has the higher probability of winning ?

Modelling the tosses with iid $X_i$, the number of $HH$ is $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} 1_{X_i=H,X_{i+1}=H}$ and the number of HT is $R_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} 1_{X_i=H,X_{i+1}=T}$.

Since the coin is fair, $E[S_n] = E[R_n]$, hence one may expect that $P(S_n>R_n) = P(R_n > S_n)$ (i.e., both players have the same probability of winning). However, simulations suggest otherwise.
Here is a plot of the (simulated) winning probabilities for each player, with $2\leq n\leq 49$ on the $x$-axis.
[image]

How can I derive which of $P(S_n>R_n)$ and  $P(R_n > S_n)$ is greater ? I tried to condition on the last outcome $X_{n+1}$, but this was a stalemate.

Source: [this twitter thread](https://twitter.com/littmath/status/1769044719034647001)

Comment: This is directly related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4882446. Where did you encounter this problem?

Comment: @joriki I've added the original Twitter thread above.

Comment: Recursive evaluation, implemented in Maple, shows that player $2$ (HT) has the advantage for all $n$ in the range $2\le n\le 1000$.