# Coin flip puzzle, prove $P(X>Y) > P(Y>X)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, puzzle

I recently encountered the following riddle:

Let a fair coin be flipped $N > 2$ times. Player A gets a point every time there are two heads in a row, and player B gets a point every time a tail is followed by a head, the player with more points wins. Thus, for example, for the sequence `THHH`, player A wins with 2 vs. 1 points while in the sequence `THHTHH`, neither wins, as they both score two points.

Clearly, the expected number of points is equal, as the sequences `HH` and `TH` are both equally likely. Now the riddle itself:

**Are player A's chances of winning higher, lower or equal to that of player B?**

I found it surprising that player A's chances of winning are lower than that of player B's.

Though there are intuitive explanations, I'd like to rigorously prove this.

Comment: This is directly related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4882364/. Where did you encounter this problem?

Comment: Duplicate of [my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4882364/more-hh-than-ht-after-tossing-n-coins).

Comment: And please edit your post to include the source of the problem.  It's unusual that two such similar questions come up at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a complete answer, but a partial attempt too long for a comment. I hope someone can turn it into a full answer, as I have to give up thinking about it for the rest of the day:

The natural sample space is $\Omega:=\{H,T\}^{N}$, equipped with the counting measure. For convenience we assume $N$ is even. Now define, for $i\in\{1,\dots,N-1\}$ the random variables $X_i^{HH}$ and $X_i^{TH}$
$$X_i^{HH}(\omega)=\begin{cases} 1 & \omega_i=H=\omega_{i+1} \\ 0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases},~ \text{and}\quad X_i^{TH}(\omega)=\begin{cases} 1 & \omega_i=T,~\text{and}~\omega_{i+1}=H \\ 0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$
Thus the scores of players $A$ and $B$ are given by the random variables
$$X_A=\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}X_i^{HH},~\text{and}~X_B=\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}X_i^{TH}.$$
As you noted, linearity of expectation and independence of different coin flips means that $\mathbb E(X_A)=\mathbb E(X_B)$. We can now use the fact that
$$\mathbb E(X_A-X_B)=\sum_{\omega\in\Omega}(X_A-X_B)(\omega)\frac{1}{2^N}$$
to see that
$$\sum_{\substack{\omega\in \Omega\\X_A(\omega)>X_B(\omega)}}(X_A-X_B)(\omega)=\sum_{\substack{\omega\in \Omega\\X_B(\omega)>X_A(\omega)}}(X_B-X_A)(\omega)$$
However, $\max_\Omega(X_A)=N-1$, but $\max_\Omega(X_B)=N/2$, so we can rewrite
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}n\mathbb P\{X_A-X_B=n\}=\sum_{n=1}^{N/2}n\mathbb P\{X_B-X_A=n\},$$
where every term in the sums are strictly positive.
Given this, the only way that we could have $\mathbb P\{X_A>X_B\}>\mathbb P\{X_B>X_A\}$ is if, for enough $n$ close enough to $N/2$, $\mathbb P\{X_B-X_A=n\}$ is sufficiently larger than $\mathbb P\{X_A-X_B=n\}$. However, we know that $\mathbb P\{X_B-X_A=N/2\}=\frac{1}{2^N}$, and by a quick inspection $\mathbb P\{X_A-X_B=N/2\}\geq\frac{N}{2^N}$, which suggests that this is very unlikely (in the intuitive, not probabilistic, meaning of the word). Thus what is left to do is to find some suitable bounds on $\mathbb P\{X_B-X_A=n\}$ and $\mathbb P\{X_A-X_B=n\}$ in terms of $n$.